# Android: HttpURLConnection redirect - doInBackground

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm using HttpURLConnection to do communication with a backend server and im doing so in an async task in the doInBackground method as you should.

Now I need to be able to follow 302 redirects, but I'm having some problems with this. The issue is that the new location usually will be on another host, however when doing the redirect request it seem not to change the URL to a new host hence I get a 404 error saying the specified path does not exits.

Now I know I could set HtppURLConnection.setFollowRedirect but I need to have more control over the redirects so they should not just be followed blindly. The Redirect behavour should be controlled by the object who called the asynctask (when an asynctask object is created you pass the object who creates it in a parameter called _callback).

Heres's my current code:

```
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... req) {
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) this._url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout( (int) this._timeout*1000);
    String body = req[0];

    // set headers / write information to output stream if request is post

    // create the response object
    HttpResponse responseObject = null;
    try
    {
        // get status, contenttype, charset...

        InputStream in = null;
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != -1 && urlConnection.getResponseCode() < 300)
        {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), 8192);
        }
        else 
        {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream(), 8192);
        }
        responseObject = new HttpResponse(in, status, contentType, charset);
        // if redirect
        if (status == 302 && this._callback.onRedirect(responseObject) == true)
        {
            // recall
            String url = urlConnection.getHeaderField("location");
            Log.v("Async Task", "Redirect location: " + url);
            this._url = null;
            this._url = new URL(url);
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            urlConnection = null;
            responseObject = this.doInBackground(req);
        }

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    // return the response
    return responseObject;

} 
// catch some other exceptions
finally 
{
    if (urlConnection != null)
    {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }   }
}
```

And as said the problem is that the redirect request seem to change the path of the URL but not the host. The URL object itself seem to contain the right information so I have no idea why this is happening. (I'm getting HTML as response which is an 404 error page that includes the server name of the old server)

Thanks for any help!

Note: HttpResponse is just an object I created for holding the relevant information about the response.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the fact that I sent the same headers and did not change the "host" header of the request which caused Apache to be confused it seems.

Comment: please post corrected code in ANSWER, but leave problematic code in QUESTION.  this solution interests me and i will upvote if code works.